# \document ->\endgroup ERROR

Tags: documentclass

These two lines:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,two column]{revtex4}%
\begin{document}
```

Produce the following error:

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.2 \begin{document}
                    
?
```

Comment: the exact error from the errors window is:

8 Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.8 \begin{document}

Comment: Do you not have an \end{document} line?

Comment: Did you check for updates? The problem should be resolved with the newest version of the class

Comment: @campa `revtex4` is no longer developed, but it did get a maintenance update a couple of weeks ago precisely to fix this error (so updating will fix the issue). But yes, it's ancient and should not be used.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ups, didn't know that. Thx for the update.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thanks!
What package should be used instead?

Comment: @GalV `revtex4-2` is the current version

Answer (score 2):

Use `\documentclass[aps,prl,two column]{revtex4-2}` instead of `\documentclass[aps,prl,two column]{revtex4}`.

Comment: Even though using `revtex4` is not recommended (it's been obsolete for decades now), it was updated to fix this particular issue.