# Extra \endgroup, missing \begin{document} compilation error

Tags: templates, compilation-error

My minimum code necessary to replicate the error is just three lines:

```
\input{report_template.cls}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I suspect its a problem with the "report_template.cls" however, this is the template we are required to use. Is there an easy work around for this type of error?

Error output in Overleaf:

```
Extra \endgroup.

\document ->\endgroup 
                      \document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {begindo...
l.3 \begin{document}
                    

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

No \begin{document} command was found. Make sure you have included \begin{document} in your preamble, and that your main document is set correctly.                                              
                                                  
l.3 \begin{document}
```

The template ".cls" file contains the following code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 

%\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
%\ProcessOptions\relax

%\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\documentclass[%
reprint,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
floatfix
]{revtex4-2}

\RequirePackage{PRL-lab}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{WLreferences}

\endinput
```

Comment: Not without knowing what's in `report_template.cls`!

Comment: Erh, one does not `\input` a class try `\documentclass{report_template}`

Comment: please provide a test that produces the error, the above produces `! LaTeX Error: File \`report_template.cls' not found.`   but using `\input` with a `.cls` file looks wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have fixed my post to include the error message

Comment: That is still no use to anyone trying to help.  why are you using `\input` with  a .cls file? that is almost certainly wrong. every other .cls file in the tex distribution is used as `\documentclass{file}` not `\input{file.cls}` But if you want people to _reproduce_ the error as you say in the question you need to show the `report_template.cls` file.

Comment: That said it is possible that your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568112/document-endgroup-error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the code for the .cls file. I'm unsure why it's included in that way, this is all from the default file we are supplied by my university as a template for our reports

Comment: so it is a duplicate of the linked one, reference an updated revtex (and tell whoever maintains that template to rename it to `.tex` !!!)

Comment: I've tried renaming it to .tex. What do you mean by referencing an updated revtex? It is referencing 4-2 which I think is the latest version

Comment: yes but (most likely) you are using an older version of revtex4-2 as the current version was updated to fix this check your log for the revtex version, it should say `2020/10/03 4.2e`