# Extra \endgroup ... \begin{document} ... LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors

I have basic-miktex-22.10-x on Windows 10. I saw a discussion of similar error in the Internet but did not see an answer clear for me (I am a simple user without deep understanding of the program). I have been using earlier versions of LaTeX for many years but never encountered such a problem. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,amsmath,eqsecnum,fleqn]{revtex4}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \newcommand{\arccosh}{\mbox{arccosh}}
 \begin{document} 
In $n$ region of the material there are charged donors and electrons excited from these donors 
 \end{document}
```

and texing gives

> ! Extra \endgroup. \document ->\endgroup \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set... l.10 \begin{document} ? ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Where have you seen "Extra \endgroup ... \begin{document} ... LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}"? Have you an example that you can put here?

Comment: Here is an example of tex file that produces the error \documentclass[preprint,aps,amsmath,eqsecnum,fleqn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}


\newcommand{\arccosh}{\mbox{arccosh}}

\begin{document}




In $n$ region of the material there are charged donors and electrons excited from these donors


\end{document} and texing gives ! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.10 \begin{document}
                     
? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your error is due to improper use of `newcommand` or a not updated version of the LaTeX's distribution or a basic MikTeX (You are probably using commands that are not contained in the basic version). Here there is your full compilable example.

```
 \documentclass[preprint,aps,amsmath,eqsecnum,fleqn]{revtex4}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{arccosh}
 \begin{document} 
In $n$ region of the material there are charged donors and electrons excited from these donors $\arccosh x=0.253$.
 \end{document}
```

Here there is the screenshot:

[image]

See also this link [\document ->\endgroup ERROR](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568112/document-endgroup-error)

Comment: +1, but is option `dvips` at `graphicx` really needed?

Comment: @Zarko In my opinion I would have removed dvips. I left it because I thought the user had .eps files as an image in his document. Thank you very much.